# Existence of joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ if the pdf of $X$ is $f(x;\theta)$ where $\theta$ is realization of $Y$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have been wondering this since last night when I read about Bayesian inference. More precisely, the set up is like this.

**$X$ takes values in $\mathcal{X}$ and suppose that $X$ has pdf $f(x;\theta)$, where $\theta$ itself is a random variable taking values in $\Omega$. To make it clear, I will call $Y$ the random variable whose realization is $\theta$. Suppose that $Y$ has pdf $\lambda(\theta)$. My question is, what is the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$?**

The explanation in the book, which is very logical and I understood it all, goes like this:

**We consider $f(x;\theta)$ as the conditional pdf of $X$ given $Y=\theta$. Hence, the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is $f(x,\theta)=f(x;\theta)\lambda(\theta)$.**

But I can't help but wonder what the rigorous justification for this explanation was. I know that if $X$ and $Y$ has a joint pdf then I can find the conditional pdf of $X$ given $Y=\theta$ by dividing the joint pdf by the pdf of $Y$. Over here, I do not have the joint pdf to start with. I know how to construct the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ if they are not related in this particular way, but in this case, I am not sure.

There is one thing that pops up in my mind that I think maybe related to, and can justify, this question. This thing is about transition probability kernel and a way of constructing product measures that I read in a probability book a while ago. I will reread it but in the mean time, I will be appreciate if you have any thought about my question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that $f(x;\theta)$ is the *conditional* probability density function when given $\theta$ as the realisation of $Y$.

This is more usually written as something like $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid \theta)$.

Likewise $\lambda(\theta)$ would be written as $f_Y(\theta)$, the *marginal* probability density function for $Y$.

So you'd have the *joint* probability density function : $$f_{X,Y}(x, \theta)= f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid \theta)~f_Y(\theta)\qquad\text{or}\qquad f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid \theta)=\dfrac{f_{X,Y}(x,\theta)}{f_Y(\theta)}$$

Where they have written: $$f(x,\theta) = f(x; \theta)~\lambda(\theta)\qquad\text{or}\qquad f(x;\theta)=\dfrac{f(x,\theta)}{\lambda(\theta)}$$

**tl;dr** It's just a notation difference.

Comment: Hi Graham, thank you for your answer. However, I am (were) aware of what you said, and I my question is not about that. Think about it this way. Why do people take it for granted that $f(x;\theta)$ is the conditional density $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid \theta)$? I know that it makes sense, but I want a rigorous set up.